# How to remove a file from a git commit to push to svn

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, commit, git-amend

I replaced a folder and all its contents with a symlink. That is removed the folder and added a symlink, in a single git commit.

Git commit happened normally. However when I try to push to the upstream svn, it complains that the file exists.

Now, how do I amend my commit to not contain the git add of the new symlink and make it a new commit, so SVN can understand to remove and replace the folder; or can I use the svn commit force via git amend.

This is the error I get:

```
RA layer file already exists: File '/svn/uswaretech_zobpress/site_media/frontend' already exists at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 508
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the file from the `HEAD` commit:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~
git rm /path/to/symlink
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: This is simple. But I want it removed from the parent commit